# Unresolve external symbols when using v8.dll in my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, v8, ninja

I'm new to making C++ project. I may be not sure prerequisite knowledge of C++ project.

**[My environment]**

- Windows 10
- Python 2.7.18
- Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022
- Visual Studio 2022 Community

---

I'm currently straggling with making V8 engine as a DLL and using it.

I've built V8 engine as a DLL successfly but using it I'm facing "Unresolve exteranl symbols" error.

Details:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::unique_ptr<class v8::Platform,struct std::default_delete<class v8::Platform> > __cdecl v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int,enum v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport,enum v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping,class std::unique_ptr<class v8::TracingController,struct std::default_delete<class v8::TracingController> >)" (?NewDefaultPlatform@platform@v8@@YA?AV?$unique_ptr@VPlatform@v8@@U?$default_delete@VPlatform@v8@@@std@@@std@@HW4IdleTaskSupport@12@W4InProcessStackDumping@12@V?$unique_ptr@VTracingController@v8@@U?$default_delete@VTracingController@v8@@@std@@@4@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ezv8::Platform::Impl::Impl(void)" (??0Impl@Platform@ezv8@@QEAA@XZ)
```

---

I've researched some thing that C++ mangling and compailer behaviours are.

I've noticed that the `v8_libplatform.dll.lib` file contains other type of mangled symbols like below.

```
?NewDefaultPlatform@platform@v8@@YA?AV?$unique_ptr@VPlatform@v8@@U?$default_delete@VPlatform@v8@@@__1@std@@@__1@std@@HW4IdleTaskSupport@12@W4InProcessStackDumping@12@V?$unique_ptr@VTracingController@v8@@U?$default_delete@VTracingController@v8@@@__1@std@@@45@@Z = ?NewDefaultPlatform@platform@v8@@YA?AV?$unique_ptr@VPlatform@v8@@U?$default_delete@VPlatform@v8@@@__1@std@@@__1@std@@HW4IdleTaskSupport@12@W4InProcessStackDumping@12@V?$unique_ptr@VTracingController@v8@@U?$default_delete@VTracingController@v8@@@__1@std@@@45@@Z (class std::__1::unique_ptr<class v8::Platform,struct std::__1::default_delete<class v8::Platform> > __cdecl v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int,enum v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport,enum v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping,class std::__1::unique_ptr<class v8::TracingController,struct std::__1::default_delete<class v8::TracingController> >))
```

As you can see, the `.lib` file contains the symbol with `__1` namespace.

I found out why the file contains that. A bundled clang compiler compiles `std` namespace with inline namespace `__1` but I'm not sure that how I can change compililng without `__1` inline namespace.

Does anyone know how to change the compiler behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem myself. (But I get still other erros in building.)

What the problem is that I have to add a flag "is_clang = false" to `gn args` because the clang that is bound v8 will compile other type of manglings to MSVS.

If I added the flag then v8 tools will compile these code with cl.exe you installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same linking issue with `v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform()` function, as well as some other methods like `v8::Context::Scope::Scope()`, `v8::Context::Scope::~Scope()` and so on. And the cause wasn't related with name mangling, it looks like clang-cl (used in v8/chromium by default on Windows platforms) uses the same name mangling as cl does. All these methods are defined in header files so they're effectively inlines, and clang-cl uses `/Zc:DllexportInlines-` compiler option which doesn't export inlines from DLLs (see https://reviews.llvm.org/D51340?id=172304 for details).

A request for adding `/Zc:DllexportInlines` option to cl compiler was raised a long time ago: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/implement-zcdllexportinlines-aka-fvisibility-inlin/374754 , but as of now, cl version 19.34.31937 still doesn't support it.

So I can see no way using v8 DLLs with Microsoft's cl compiler without modifying v8/chromium header files (which is never good). One can build v8 as static libraries, or use clang-cl as a custom build tool.

As for building v8 without clang using `is_clang=false` gn argument, I wonder if it's actually possible. There are many compiler options like `-Wno-unused-const-variable` or `-Wno-unused-function` which aren't supported by cl but added unconditionally in gn build files. I remember years ago it was possible to build chromium using cl, but is it now?